# Пример работы с WMI из под Qt5

Tags: c++, windows, qt5, wmi

Ребят подскажите существуют ли стандартные методы для работы с WMI из под Qt. 
В доках нашёл какой-то QAxObject а примеров нет. Как использовать смутно представляю.

Comment: зачем такое извращение? что за задача стоит ?

Comment: Читать события и Windows Event Log используя Qt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пример работы с WMI с использованием QAxObject  [Ссылка](https://poofeg.ru/2010/06/wmi-i-qt-problemy-s-ienum/), есть немного костыльные варианты  выполнения powershell скриптов которые орудуют с WMI и разбора результата их выполнения [Пример](http://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/lUV0YvuI/executing-powershell-command-with-quotes-using-qprocess)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft уже описал работы с WMI [Creating a WMI Application Using C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389762(VS.85).aspx)
Ты можешь реализовать какой-нибудь интерфейс для работы с этим, а можешь генерировать уже классы. Подробнее [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/2wkebaxa(v=vs.110).aspx). Я рекомендую сгененрировать. 
Подробнее о [WMI-классах](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/aa394554(v=vs.85).aspx) можно тут почитать.

Также можете использовать `PowerShell` для получения доступа к `WMI-объектам`. Примеры на `PS` можете посмотреть [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tags-cloud.aspx?tag=powershell%20code%20wmi).

[Примеры](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394558(v=vs.85).aspx) на C++

Также на сайте `codeProject` есть очень хорошая [информация](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10539/Making-WMI-Queries-In-C) об этом. Там уже есть готовые примеры [кода](https://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ViewDownloads.aspx?aid=10539) с комментариями  (Не хочется дублировать это сюда)